# How to create sub folder in a folder using VBA

Tags: vba, directory, subdirectory

Need suggestions here as I am creating a folder using `MkDir` and the folder name is an input in a cell from the user.
After creating this folder I further need to create sub folder.
`strOrderNo` stores the input value from the user.

Following is the code used and though the *order no* folder is created, not able to create sub folder invoices.

```
On Error Resume Next

MkDir "C\" & strOrderNo

MkDir "C\strOrderNo\Invoices"

On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Note that because of `On Error Resume Next` you don't see your error messages (it turns off all error messages). Because you don't see them, you don't know which the error message is, and that is why you cannot fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using the `strOrderNo` in a `mkdir` string, rather than the variable.

Assuming the first `mkdir` is behaving how you want it, the second needs to be:

```
MkDir "C" & strOrderNo & "\Invoices"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"C:\" & strOrderNo` ?

Comment: only if it was meant to be that with the first mkdir as well. hence my 'assuming' disclaimer :)